# How to return text of node without child nodes text

Tags: xslt, return

I have xml like:

```
<item id="1">
        <items>
            <item id="2">Text2</item>
            <item id="3">Text3</item>
        </items>Text1
</item>
```

How to return text of `<item id="1">`('Text1')? 
`<xsl:value-of select="item/text()"/>` returns nothing.

My XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
     </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
     <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I dont know what else to type to commit my edits

Comment: It depends on what the current context is (i.e what the current node is). In your case, you would have to positioned on parent of the `item` element. Can you show us your current XSLT, as that would clarify things. Thanks.

Comment: <pre><?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="item_key" match="item" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
    
  </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
 <li>
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
 </li>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet></pre>

Comment: Can you actually edit your question to include the XSLT, rather than add a comment? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> How to return text of `<item id="1">`('Text1')? `<xsl:value-of
>   select="item/text()"/>` returns nothing.

The `item` element has more than one text-node children and the first of them happens to be a all-whitespace one -- this is why you get "nothing".

One way to test if the string value  of a node isn't all-whitespace is by using the `normalize-space()` function.

**In a single Xpath expression, you want this**:

```
/*/text()[normalize-space()][1]
```

**Here is a complete transformation the result of which is the desired text node:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="text()[normalize-space()][1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<item id="1">
        <items>
            <item id="2">Text2</item>
            <item id="3">Text3</item>
        </items>Text1
</item>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Text1
```

Comment: Is your solution preferable to `<xsl:value-of select="text()[normalize-space()]"/>` in any way?

Comment: @Borodin, Yes. While the two XPath expressions are equivalent in XSLT 1.0/ XPath 1.0, they have different results in XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0. The XPath expression in my answer produces the right result in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. It has the added value of clearly showing which of the many possible selected nodes will be output.

Answer (score 2):

This should generally work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item/text()" />
```

Incorporated into your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="item_key" match="item" use="."/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Text1
</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, this should work as well:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="item/text()" />
```